# CSS блок на экрана 16:9

Tags: css

Есть блок и в нем еще 3 блока каждый 270 пикселей на мониторах 4:3. Все нормально, но на широкоформатных появляется отступ справа. Кто знает, как исправить? (Вся страница работает, как надо, только блок посередине - нет.)

Answer (score 1):

В широкоформатных разрешение больше.

div`ы по своей природе тянутся на всю доступную ширину и потому родительский блок шире на широкоформатнике. Отсюда и отступ.

Зафиксируй родительскому блоку ширину нужную стилями. Если у тебя 3 дива по 270 пикселей шириной - поставь родителю ширину в 810 пикселей.

Comment: вся проблема в томчто у меня родительский див 890 пикселей

Comment: значит добавьте код блоков со стилями, скриншоты с обычного и широкоформатника.

Тогда смогут помочь, а так это больше походит на предсказания :)

Comment: я вроде разобрался почти дело в том что этот код идет с другой страницы и на экране 4:3 почему то работает а на широких если проверит инспектором свойства блока все равно 172 пикселя

Answer (score 0):

К общему div`у добавьте margin:0 auto;